# Flip items in UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a section in my app where I am changing views by using a `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft` animation. At the same time, I change the contents of the `UINavigationItem` to match the new view, specifically the `titleView` and `rightBarButtonItem`. Since I only really know when the animation is about to start, and has finished, this seems to be the only times that I can update the UINavigationItem.

So, to my question:

1. Is it possible to change the `titleView` and `rightBarButtonItem` in a similar fashion, ie. flipping with a `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft` animation?
2. If not, is there any way that I can update the `UINavigationItem` halfway through the view flip, rather than at the start or end of the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve 1.

You'll need full control of the navigation bar to do this so you should get rid of the one that's there using:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

on your UIViewController and putting your own navBar view there instead (which would have a subview that's the titleView and the rightBarButtonItem). That way, you can flip those views as you would any other UIView using:

```
+[UIVIew setAnimationTransition:(UIViewAnimationTransition)transition forView:(UIView *)view cache:(BOOL)cache]
```

or

```
+[UIVIew transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion]
```

or something equivalent. Hope this helps, ping me if you need more details.

Comment: I'm going to trust that this works without having tried it yet, but just wondering, do you have any idea why this should work, and leaving the standard nav bar in doesn't?

Comment: Yes, the standard UIKit nav bar does some things to the titleView (ie: centering it among other things) when it transitions so you won't be able to get the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` to do the transition, you'll know the duration. That means you can use
`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method to run a method after half of the transition has been done. In this method you can then just update your navigation item.

Comment: I don't disagreeing with huesforalice, but the problem is transitioning that view isn't a robust solution since you're assuming iOS will not change the internal behaviour of that class (even today that class autocenters the view depending on how the transition occurred, so it's not really designed to have that effect applied to it).

Comment: This is an interesting approach, makes sense. I'll give this a try if I can't get the items flipping.